# while loop runs fine with user input via prompt, but not with textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

This is part of a school homework assignment and I can't figure out what's going on. I'm modifying a previous project I did to change a prompt to a textbox for user input. The prompt works fine, the while loop executes as it should. Once I switch to the textbox the loop runs through it's full course all the way to the end automatically without even letting me enter a single number. What is inherently different about a textbox that makes it not work correctly in my application? I've included the original prompt that was working correctly and commented it out.

I'm including everything from the project, but my only real concern right now is the while loop in the JS and perhaps my textbox in the HTML. Please help me to find where I made the error that causes the loop to not run correctly. Thanks!

JS

```
var ranNum;

//Main function for the game logic
function playGame() {

//Declaring variables
var answer;
var found = false;
var count = 6;
var runningcount = 5;


//While loop runs while user has guesses remaining and has not found answer.
while ((count > 0) && (found == false))
{
    //answer = prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 50!");
    answer = document.getElementById('userGuess');


    //If user presses cancel this will display
    if (answer === null) {
       document.getElementById('guesses').innerHTML += "I guess you are choosing to end the game now? See you next time!<br /><br />";
       document.getElementById("startButton").disabled = true
       return
    }

    //This ensures the answer entered is a number
    answer = parseInt(answer);

    //If the answer is not a number, this is displayed
    if (isNaN(answer)) {
        document.getElementById('guesses').innerHTML += "That is not a number! Enter a number! You wasted a guess! You now have " + runningcount + " guesses remaining. <br /><br />"

    }

    //Response if user guesses too high.
    if (answer > ranNum) {
        document.getElementById('guesses').innerHTML += "Your guess of " + answer + " was too high! You now have " + runningcount + " guesses remaining. <br /><br />"

    }

    //Response if user guesses too low
    if (answer < ranNum) {
        document.getElementById('guesses').innerHTML += "Your guess of " + answer + " was too low! You now have " + runningcount + " guesses remaining. <br /><br />"

    }

    //Response if user guesses correctly
    if (answer == ranNum) {
        document.getElementById('guesses').innerHTML += "Your guess of " + answer + " is correct! <br /><br />";
        found = true;
        document.getElementById("startButton").disabled = true;
    }


    //Subtracts one from the remaining count after each guess
    count--;

    //Subtracts one from the displayed remaining guesses after each guess
    runningcount--;
}

//Once the user runs out of guesses, this logic is executed.
if (!found) {
    document.getElementById('guesses').innerHTML += "Sorry you didn't guess correctly!<br /> The correct answer was " + ranNum + "<br /><br /> Please press New Game to try again.<br />";
    document.getElementById("startButton").disabled = true;
}


return found;

}

function switchVisible() {
if (document.getElementById('startScreen')) {

    if (document.getElementById('startScreen').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('startScreen').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('gameScreen').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('startScreen').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('gameScreen').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
}

//This is the function that generates the random number each time
function generateRandomNumber()
{
ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
}

//This executes the the random number function as soon as the page loads
window.onload = function ()
{
generateRandomNumber();
}



//This is the function for reloading the page when the user selects New Game.
function newGame() {
location.reload(true);
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="startScreen">

    <h2> Guessing Game! Press Start to Play! </h2>
    <button id="startButton" onclick="switchVisible(); playGame(); ">Start Game!</button>

    <hr />
    <br />

</div>

<div id="gameScreen">
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="userGuess" />

    <br />
    <button id="newButton" onclick="newGame(); switchVisible(); ">New Game!</button><hr />
    <br />

    <span id="guesses">
    </span>
```

CSS

```
#startScreen
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 250px;
width: 650px;
height: auto;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 15px;
text-align: center;
border-color: red;

}

#gameScreen
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 250px;
width: 650px;
height: auto;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 15px;
text-align: center;
border-color: red;
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Alert boxes stop execution while a textbox doesn't. If you want the textbox to work like an alert it will require a different architecture completely most likely as there is no way to delay the loop (aside maybe a complex async loop using promise objects http://blog.victorquinn.com/javascript-promise-while-loop)

Comment: @KevinF what do you mean by a different architecture? Do I need to restructure the loop?

Comment: I guess it depends on how the game is played. Do they type something and click a guess button and then logic runs? Or does the logic run if they stop typing for a couple hundred ms?